# Can you tell how or what was used to create an Android game?

Tags: android

Could you look at an app (simply as a user) and tell how it was made or what library (if any) were used?  I'm thinking about making a game like Devil's Attorney, but I'm really going back and forth with something. That something is whether to use a 2D library like libgdx, HTML5 (phonegap), or just use the standard Android library. The game I'm looking at as an example, almost looks like a really juiced up HTML5 app, but.. I can't tell. So, is there a way to kind of know what platform and/or library was used in making an Android game? This is related strictly to popular/successful Android game apps that aren't open source.

Comment: reverse-engineer the APK I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out which libraries are used in an Android app with the AppBrain Ad Detector (main purpose is to detect ad networks, but it also detects popular libraries such as libgdx, cocos2d, unity etc)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.detector

Comment: That actually works. I can't believe I got an answer to a question you can't Google. Thanks!

Comment: The only bad thing is that I really can't tell what was used to create a game app (well, your answer is about 80% good, so I'm awarding it as the answer). Example: I can't tell how they made the Kim Kardashian app. Just shows basic libraries. Well, thanks again.